# How to use HMAC SHA256?

Tags: sha256, hmac

As per the various docs that I have read for using HMAC SHA256, I have understood that:

H (K XOR opad, H (K XOR ipad, text)) where H in my case is SHA256.

But, SHA256 input has only one parameter i.e a Message.
Whereas H(K,text) has two inputs.
So how to calculate H(k,text)?

Should I first encode text with k and then use H(encoded_text), where encoded_text will be used as a message?

Thank You

Comment: Your suggested operation would be valid, though expensive.  It would be easier to do something like `H(H(M).K)` where H() denotes a hash operation, . denotes appending, and M and K denote message and key.

Comment: H() does not have 2 seperators, your "," should be an || (concatenation), see example in my answer below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- H() is your cryptographic hash function, in this case SHA256() but
  could also be MD5 or whatever;
- K is your predifined key
- Text is the message to be authenticated
- opad be the outer padding (0x5c5c5c…5c5c, one-block-long hexadecimal
  constant)
- ipad be the inner padding  (0x363636…3636, one-block-long hexadecimal
  constant)
- Then HMAC(K,m)  is mathematically defined by

HMAC(K,m) = H((K ⊕ opad)    ∥ H((K ⊕ ipad)    ∥ m)).

- blocksized is determined by your hash function (MD5 would be 64
  bytes)
- o_key_pad = [opad * blocksize] ⊕ key
- i_key_pad = [ipad * blocksize] ⊕ key

Your result would be:

```
H(o_key_pad || H(i_key_pad || TEXT))
```

You can find a good read here:
http://timdinh.nl/index.php/hmac/

With also the following pseudocode which almost looks like mine :

```
function hmac (key, message)
    opad = [0x5c * blocksize] // Where blocksize is that of the underlying hash function
    ipad = [0x36 * blocksize]

    if (length(key) > blocksize) then
        key = hash(key) // Where 'hash' is the underlying hash function
    end if

    for i from 0 to length(key) - 1 step 1
        ipad[i] = ipad[i] XOR key[i]
        opad[i] = opad[i] XOR key[i]
    end for

    return hash(opad || hash(ipad || message)) // Where || is concatenation
end function
```